# Is it possible to retrieve Google Vault activities using API

Tags: google-workspace, google-admin-audit-api, google-vault-api

It seems that https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list does not support google vault, and https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest doesn't mention the audit log either.
I know how do it manually, using the web console, but my question is, is it possible to do it using the API provided by google?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is not possible to do using a Google API.*

#### Feature Request:

On the flip side however, Google already knows about this, and a Feature Request for this has been made on their Issue Tracker. You can view this feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/120242241), to which you can click the star (☆) in the top left to let Google know more people want this feature to be implemented.

#### References:

- [Audit reporting functionality #api #audit-logs](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120242241)